# API Platform: Failed to load private key

Tags: api-platform.com

I am trying to setup API Platform with the documented setup:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/

I have loaded fixtures in the following way:

```
#src/DataFixtures/AppFixtures.php
private function loadUsers(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $users = $this->getUserData();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $_user = new User();
        $_user->setUsername($user['username']);
        $_user->setPassword($user['password']);
        $_user->setEmail($user['email']);
        $_user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($_user, $user['password']));

        $manager->persist($_user);
    }

    $manager->flush();
}

private function getUserData()
{
    $users = array(
        ['first_name'=>'John','last_name'=>'Doe','username'=>'johndoe','email'=>'johndoe@gmail.com','password'=>'test'],

    return $users;
}
```

My security.yml looks like this:

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_READER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_READER

providers:
    jwt_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Now I want to try to get a token:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe -d _password=test
```

But im getting a non-json response. Somewhere I find the message:

```
my-imac:project-folder measauser$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=johndoe@gmail.com -d _password=test

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>    Failed to load private key &quot;/Users/measauser/Sites/project-folder/config/jwt/private.pem&quot;: 
 06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
 0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt (500 Internal Server Error)
```

This is my .env file:

```
###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
# Key paths should be relative to the project directory
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=42761e3ad1eb66faf082ac0763e46a2d
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
```

1) why is this message actually not in json?

2) why is this error happening?

3) im also unable to reach the docs as I find the message {"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"} in the browser

Could anyone help me out?

**UPDATE:**
For 2) it seems that the JWT_PASSPHRASE in .env was not correctly matching the passphrase I typed. So this part has been solved.

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282372/api-platform-jwt-no-route-found-for-get-api-login

Comment: Thanks but 1) and 3) are not answered. I figured the jwt_passphrase was not current. So 2) has been solved.